# Returning int in a function with Future, async, await to add at Firestore - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm trying to return a int in this function:

```
  Future<int> getID() async {
    DocumentSnapshot idSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Bestellungen")
        .doc("default")
        .get();
    int currentID = idSnapshot["id"] + 1;
    return await currentID;
  }
```

and now I want to use it right here in a onTap-methode of my GestureDetector:

```
onTap: () {
                                Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection("Bestellungen")
                                    .add({
                                  "id": getID(),
                                  "item": document["titel"],
                                  "done": false,
                                  "time": getTime(),
                                });
                              }
```

However, if I tap my button the application crashs and it showed me following in VS Code:

[image: Error]

I think the problem is connected to the Future, async and await.
I also tried to set an await before getID() but for that a async is also needed but I dont know where to include it in my Stateful class if its the right way.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Instead of showing us a screenshot of the debugger, can you show us the exact error message and complete stack trace that you get?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work:

```
"id": getID(),
```

Since `getID` returns a `Future<int>`, you're trying to set a `Future` to thd database, and that is not a supported type.

This should work:

```
"id": await getID(),
```

As now you are waiting for the `Future` to be resolved.

Comment: Tried that as well, but I need to add async somewhere in my code that adds it to the database. Do you know where?

Comment: https://flutter.institute/run-async-operation-on-widget-creation I found that one. I think that should be the solution. I will try it in a few minutes.

Comment: @Thoxh Or use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Since the only use of the async `getID()` here  is within `onTap` and that doesn't return a widget, I wasn't sure how to use a `FutureBuilder`. But if that is indeed possible, I'd love to see an answer where you show how. 